# "Page-Specific Javascript" using stimulusjs on rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, stimulusjs

May I know, can we achieve "Page-Specific Javascript" loading as mentioned in [Organizing Javascript in Rails Application With Turbolinks](http://brandonhilkert.com/blog/organizing-javascript-in-rails-application-with-turbolinks/) article using the [stimulusjs](https://github.com/stimulusjs/stimulus) framework ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, though it's more "component-specific".

With Stimulus, you can add `data-controller` to any element, and at any time that elements is in the DOM, appropriate controller will be invoked. No need for `$(document).ready` or `$(document).on("turbolinks:load")` — everything happens automatically.

You can read more in [Stimulus Handbook](https://stimulusjs.org/handbook/introduction).